# Iterate through a groupby array of json

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angularjs, grouping

I have an array of JSON object as follows

```
 var array = [{"id":"1","value": "13"},{"id":"2","value": "23"},{"id":"1","value": "33"},{"id":"3","value": "13"}]
```

Then I grouped the json array according to the id as follows

```
var groupArray = {"1":[{"id":"1","value": "13"},{"id":"1","value": "33"}],
                     "2": [{"id":"2","value": "23"}],
                     "3": [{"id":"3","value": "13"}]};
```

I want to iterate through **groupArray** and get the total of value for each id where duplicate ids should sum up together and give one single total value and assign them into another array as follows

```
resultArray
[{"id":"1","value":"46"},{"id":"2","value":"23"},{"id":"3","value":"13"}]
```

This should be achieved using angularjs

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I want to iterate through the grouped array and get resultArray as shown above. I have no idea how to iterate through the grouped array of json

Comment: Is `groupArray` and array as the name suggests or an object as the `{ }` suggest?

Comment: I think it's a hash, so we would have to do a for loop and index the hash values i would think in order to get to the array

Comment: groupArray is an object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easier if `groupArray` was in fact an array. As an object you have to be aware that order has not always been guaranteed, but it's not clear if the order of your final array is important. In recent JS it shouldn't matter — numeric keys will be sorted. You can just call `map()` on the `Object.values()`, then use `reduce()` on each array:

```js
var groupArray = {
    "1":[{"id":"1","value": "13"},{"id":"1","value": "33"}],
    "2": [{"id":"2","value": "23"}],
    "3": [{"id":"3","value": "13"}]
}

let sums = Object.values(groupArray)
           .map(arr => arr.reduce((sums,{id, value}) => ({id, value: sums.value + +value}), {value:0}))
console.log(sums)
```

You need to be aware that `value` is a string and make sure you are adding numbers not concatenating strings when you use `+`.

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
const object = {}
const array = [{"id":"1","value": "13"},{"id":"2","value": "23"},{"id":"1","value": "33"},{"id":"3","value": "13"}]

array.forEach(data => {
  object[data.id] = parseInt(data.value, 10) + (object[data.id] || 0)
})

const result = Object.entries(object).map(data => {
  return {
    'id': data[0],
    'value': data[1]
  }
})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Object.entries` to get the object keys and values as an array then iterate through the values in order to sum up the `value` inside each object and then push it with its `id` to `resultArray`.

```js
let groupArray = {"1":[{"id":"1","value": "13"},{"id":"1","value": "33"}],"2": [{"id":"2","value": "23"}],"3": [{"id":"3","value": "13"}]}
let resultArray = []
Object.entries(groupArray).forEach(g => {
  let sumValue = 0
  g[1].forEach(o => sumValue += parseFloat(o.value))
  resultArray.push({
    "id": g[0],
    "value": sumValue.toString()
  })
})
console.log(resultArray)
```

Comment: Since he is asking for AngularJS, ES2015 and ES2017 support should be mentioned

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `reduce` for grouping and the function `Object.values` for extracting the desired output.

```js
var array = [{"id":"1","value": "13"},{"id":"2","value": "23"},{"id":"1","value": "33"},{"id":"3","value": "13"}]
let result = Object.values(array.reduce((a, {id, value}) => {
  (a[id] || (a[id] = {id, value: 0})).value += +value;
  return a;
}, Object.create(null)));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```